# In IIS How does high CPU percentage utilisation manifest itself?

Tags: performance, iis

I am looking to implement some alerting and monitoring in my organisation and have a few questions in regards to IIS and CPU usage.

1) If there is a process (could be IIS itself) taking up a large amount of CPU resources running on the same machine as IIS, what effect does that have on client response rates? i.e. does it take much longer to reply to a clients request ?

2) In IIS land are there any gold standard metrics that should be monitored to get an idea on the "health" of the windows server running a bunch of web services i.e. CPU %, request/response times, memory etc

Comment: 1) IIS is a multi-process monster, so your assumption of "could be IIS itself" is ambiguous. If different parts of IIS consume high CPU, the impacts are also different. 2) none exists, because everyone's web apps are different. You have to use your own judgement and build up your own baseline for performance.

Comment: Its common that IIS worker process take taking up  large amount of CPU especially when your website are suffering high concurrent requests. Most of time, it won't  have much performance impact on response speed as long as no request hang in IIS. Besides, How do you identify "high cpu"? 30% and 99% could indicate different meaning.